# How should I make the following mongoDB query?

Tags: mongodb, crud

Suppose I have the following MongoDB index:

- Day (1-365)
- Hour (0-23)
- Second (0-3599)

Prepared by:

```
db.coll.ensureIndex({Day:1, Hour:1, Second:1})
```

The documents are in the form of:

```
{ Day: 1, Hour: 10, Second: 1200, Price: 100}
{ Day: 1, Hour: 10, Second: 1201, Price: 101}
{ Day: 1, Hour: 10, Second: 1202, Price: 103}
{ Day: 1, Hour: 10, Second: 1203, Price: 102}
{ Day: 1, Hour: 10, Second: 1204, Price: 101}
```

In essence it is the price movement over time of certain goods.

How should I form a mongoDB query that extract data with the following range:

```
min: {Day: 1, Hour: 10, Second: 2400}
max: {Day: 1, Hour: 12, Second: 1200}
```

I want manual examine the data because I got an chunkTooBig error as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28823367/mongodb-balancer-move-failed-due-to-chunk-too-big-even-after-increasing-chunksiz)

If the range of data is:

```
min: {Day: 1, Hour: 10, Second: 1200}
max: {Day: 1, Hour: 10, Second: 2400}
```

The I can easily form a query by:

```
db.coll.find({Day:1, Hour:10, Second:{$gte:1200, $lt:2400}})
```

I think I'm probably missing something obvious here, can someone shed some light on me? Thank you!

Comment: I think possibly you should have just edited your other question since it does not explain what you were doing there. Again this is not really clear either. Are these values in separate documents or in the same document or what exactly?

Comment: hmm.. since the other question is about sharding while this one is about query, I would prefer keeping both. These values are in different documents. I want to query a range of documents. I have edited the question, hope it is making more sense. Sorry for the bad description

Comment: I makes it clearer what you are doing but what is the problem? I see no problem apart from a reference to another question talking about an error received from a sharded cluster operation. Presumably this is the query you are running and that is the error? Totally in the dark.

Comment: The solution may seems clear to most people.. but I am confused on querying document from the range {Hour:10, Second:2400} to {Hour:12, Second:1200}. note the difference in value of field "Hour". Would be great if someone can provide me the corresponding query

Comment: Why aren't you using a date type?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried combining the $or and $and operators. From your description it looks to me like your query should be of the form:

Where Day is 10 AND 
  (Hour is 10 or more and Seconds are greater than or equal to 2400)
  AND
  (Hour is 12 or less and Seconds are less than or equal to 1200)

Does that better express what you are trying to do? I.e. you need to take into account the Hours field too.

Which would give a query similar to:

```
 db.coll.find({
  $and: [
     { Day : 1 },
     { $or: [ 
             { $and: [ 
                       { Hour : 10 },
                       { Second : { $gte : 2400 } } 
                     ] },
             { Hour : { $gt : 10 } } 
            ] },
     { $or: [ 
             { $and: [ 
                      { Hour : 12 },
                      { Second : { $lte : 1200 } } 
                     ] },
             { Hour : { $lt : 12 } } 
             ] } 
    ]
});
```

I've tried this with data and it gives the results I expect. Hope this solves your problem for you.

Comment: I think there is something wrong in your query? Seems like it is not a valid json

Comment: That's possible as it was typed on a mobile on a train. Does what it is trying to do help you any and take you closer to an answer? If so we can look to fix the JSON.

Comment: Yes please! I believe the answer is a combination of $and and $or operators.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'm away from the database will try it as soon as possible. btw, wouldn't all documents be returned using the $or operator in this scenario? Since anything >=  2400 or  <=1200 will be returned?

Comment: I have tried your query last night, the query took quite long and it seems traversing the whole collections. But no problem man! I appreciate your help!

Comment: Thank you very much for staying with me. Sadly I modeled the question for easier illustration. The real schema has little to do with date and time and hence cannot be replaced with ISODate :(

Comment: I had another look at the query and firstly using aggregate operations managed to get what I think you are looking for. I then managed to translate that to a query. Hope this gives you your answer.